# Extract vector of unquoted strings from string of quoted strings

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a string of the form:

```
str<-"    'A'    'B'    'csdsdf3' 'csdsdf3' "
```

I'm looking for the simplest function `u<-extract(str)`, which gives

```
u=c("A","B","csdsdf3", "csdsdf3")
```

I already tried `strsplit`, but it doesn't give the desired result. I'm using R relatively seldom and I'm overwhelmed by the multitude of functions. Most likely a regular expression could be helpful to extract the strings inside the quotes, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use `scan`?

```
scan(what = "", text = str)
# Read 4 items
# [1] "A"       "B"       "csdsdf3" "csdsdf3"
```

Comment: That really works. Many thanks. I'm using R only sometimes and so it is hard to find the correct functions.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_extract` to match characters that are not a `'` or space

```
library(stringr)
u1 <- str_extract_all(str, "[^' ]+")[[1]]
identical(u, u1)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or if we use `strsplit`, split on the `'` and space

```
u2 <- strsplit(str, "[' ]")[[1]]
u2[nzchar(u2)]
```